# Issues with OBIEE Parent-Child Hierarchy Drilldown

Tags: oracle, hierarchy, obiee

I have a parent-child hierarchy that goes 4 level deep with a structure similar like this, where everything is connected via member-ancestor:

```
level1
    level2
    level2
    level2
        level3
            level4
    level2
```

I've created the table from the scripts created with the Administration Tool. Everything seems to work fine.

But when i create a Analysis and drill down the hierarchy, i can only get to level2. When i try to go deeper nothing happens.It wont load elements from level 3, even though i can select elements from level 3 and 4 in the selection steps -> new step -> select members screen.

Do you have an idea why i'm not getting results on the third level?

It's on OBIEE 12.2.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OBIEE didn't like that the root had a 0 as member_id, i don't know exactly why that would be a problem but after the root element got a 1 as member_id and the parent_ids got updated to 1 as well i was able to drill down correctly.